# My chat website(php+ajax) makes my browser stuck

Tags: php, ajax, chat

This is the script I use for various purposes like scrolling, getting the data from php etc:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#full_chat").animate({ scrollTop: $('#full_chat')[0].scrollHeight+1000}, 1500);
  setInterval(function refreshPage() { 
     var user=$("#head").text();
     $.post("retrieve.php",{ user:user }, function(data,status){
        if($.trim(data)!="0"){
            $("#full_chat").append("<span class='you'>"+data+"</span>");
            $('#full_chat').emoticonize();
            window.onblur = function () {
                $('#full_chat').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
                    $.titleAlert("New Message!", {
                        requireBlur:true,                                               
                        stopOnFocus:true,
                        //duration:10000,                                               
                        //interval:500
                    });
                });
            }
        }
  }); }, 1500);


$("#form").on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user=$("#head").text();
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

    var txt= $("#chat_input").val();
    $.post("chat.php",{ txt:txt,user:user,time:time },function(data,status){
        if(data=="OFFLINE"){
            $("#full_chat").append("User not available right now<br>");
        }else{
            $("#full_chat").append("("+time+")  ").append("<span class='me'>"+"Me: "+txt+"</span><br>").emoticonize({delay: 1,animate:false});
        }
    });

    $("#full_chat").animate({ scrollTop: $('#full_chat')[0].scrollHeight+1000}, 1500);
        $('#chat_input').val('');
    });

});
</script>
```

This is the PHP code I use to get the chats from database:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$other_user=$_POST['user'];
$flag=$_POST['flag'];
include_once('db.php');

$uname=$_SESSION['username'];
//date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$q="select message,sender,time from chat where username='$uname' and delivered=0  and sender='$other_user' order by time ASC";
$qe = mysqli_query($con,$q);
$q1="UPDATE chat SET delivered=1  WHERE username='$uname' and sender='$other_user'" ;
$qe1 = mysqli_query($con,$q1);
if($r=mysqli_fetch_array($qe)) {
    echo "(".$r['2'].")  ". $r['1'].": ".$r['0']."<br>";
}else {
    echo "0";   
}
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

What may be the reason for the problem? Is it the page refresh that happens every 1.5 seconds or something else?

Comment: What exactly is happening when you say your browser is "stuck"? Is it freezing up? Or is nothing loading?

Comment: @Huey:  It is freezing up.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's this `emoticonize` function you've been calling with a delay of 1. Browser freezes when javascript is involved often mean you have an infinite or very long loop somewhere that is continuously running.

Comment: @Huey: emoticonize() emoticonizes the :), :( like things.

Comment: Could it be the issue? I'm not familiar with this library/jQuery plugin, but since you're calling it very often, I imagine it could be an issue. Perhaps try commenting out all references to that first? 

If not then you comment your code systematically to try and pinpoint the issue. Maybe start with the `setInterval` function, and check if the issue stems from there?

Comment: Just wondering; Why are you naming your interval callback function (refreshPage)? Is it for your own reference to see what it does?

Comment: A 1.5 seconds interval isn't much, and since the ajax calls are asynchronous, a response might not be received while another request is already on it's way. You should not use setInterval, but use a timeout in the success callback of the ajax call, which will then make another request and so on.

Comment: @jazZRo : how do i do that?

Comment: There is a maximum of ~ 8 simultanous ajax requests. When you request the chat status in 500ms interval, and your server responds in 800 seconds, it sums up pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to give you an idea, it is not tested.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var user = $("#head").text();
var postTimeout = 0;
var refreshPage = function(postInterval, postData) {
    $.post("retrieve.php", postData, function(data, status) {
        if (!postTimeout) {
            postTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                refreshPage(postInterval, postData);
                postTimeout = 0;
            }, postInterval);
        }
        if ($.trim(data) != "0") {
            $("#full_chat").append("<span class='you'>" + data + "</span>");
            $('#full_chat').emoticonize();
            window.onblur = function() {
                $('#full_chat').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
                    $.titleAlert("New Message!", {
                        requireBlur: true,
                        stopOnFocus: true,
                        //duration:10000,                                               
                        //interval:500
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
$("#full_chat").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#full_chat')[0].scrollHeight + 1000
}, 1500);

refreshPage(1500, {user: user});


$("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = $("#head").text();
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

    var txt = $("#chat_input").val();
    $.post("chat.php", {
        txt: txt,
        user: user,
        time: time
    }, function(data, status) {
        if (data == "OFFLINE") {
            $("#full_chat").append("User not available right now<br>");
        } else {
            $("#full_chat").append("(" + time + ")  ").append("<span class='me'>" + "Me: " + txt     + "</span><br>").emoticonize({
                    delay: 1,
                    animate: false
                });
            }
        });

        $("#full_chat").animate({
            scrollTop: $('#full_chat')[0].scrollHeight + 1000
        }, 1500);
        $('#chat_input').val('');
    });

});
</script>
```